cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections'
I am developing a python-flask web application using Python 3.12 and locally it works fine.
I want to deploy it on Azure using Azure App Services (Web App).
I configured the Github actions to deploy the project on Azure App Services but after the deploy (successful), when i try to reach the web site i get the error:
File "/opt/python/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/zipfile/_path/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  Ok
2024-07-21T21:26:59.6614572
    import pathlib
  Ok
2024-07-21T21:26:59.6615082
  File "/tmp/8dca9c76a13f465/antenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
  Ok
2024-07-21T21:26:59.6616163
    from collections import Sequence
  Ok
2024-07-21T21:26:59.6616728
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (/opt/python/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/collections/__init__.py)

The pathlib package is willing to import Sequence from collections instead of collections.abc; this is deprecared since Python 3.3, and not working anymore since Pyhton 3.10.
I don't get anyway why locally everything works fine (i created a dedicated virtual environment locally and i am using the corresponding requirements.txt file for the deploy) and online (after the deploy) i get that error.
Here's the result for the pip list command:
Package                                  Version
---------------------------------------- -----------
aiofiles                                 24.1.0
aiohttp                                  3.9.5
aiosignal                                1.3.1
annotated-types                          0.7.0
anyio                                    4.4.0
asgiref                                  3.8.1
asttokens                                2.4.1
async-timeout                            4.0.3
attrs                                    23.2.0
Babel                                    2.15.0
backoff                                  2.2.1
bcrypt                                   4.1.3
beautifulsoup4                           4.12.3
blinker                                  1.8.2
build                                    1.2.1
cachelib                                 0.13.0
cachetools                               5.4.0
certifi                                  2024.7.4
cffi                                     1.16.0
charset-normalizer                       3.3.2
chroma-hnswlib                           0.7.5
chromadb                                 0.5.4
ci-info                                  0.3.0
click                                    8.1.7
colorama                                 0.4.6
coloredlogs                              15.0.1
configobj                                5.0.8
configparser                             7.0.0
contourpy                                1.2.1
cryptography                             43.0.0
cycler                                   0.12.1
dataclasses-json                         0.6.7
decorator                                5.1.1
Deprecated                               1.2.14
distro                                   1.9.0
dnspython                                2.6.1
email_validator                          2.2.0
etelemetry                               0.3.1
exceptiongroup                           1.2.2
executing                                2.0.1
fastapi                                  0.111.1
fastapi-cli                              0.0.4
filelock                                 3.15.4
fitz                                     0.0.1.dev2
Flask                                    3.0.3
flask-babel                              4.0.0
Flask-Session                            0.8.0
flatbuffers                              24.3.25
fonttools                                4.53.1
frontend                                 0.0.3
frozenlist                               1.4.1
fsspec                                   2024.6.1
google-auth                              2.32.0
googleapis-common-protos                 1.63.2
greenlet                                 3.0.3
grpcio                                   1.65.1
h11                                      0.14.0
httpcore                                 1.0.5
httplib2                                 0.22.0
httptools                                0.6.1
httpx                                    0.27.0
huggingface-hub                          0.24.0
humanfriendly                            10.0
idna                                     3.7
importlib_metadata                       7.1.0
importlib_resources                      6.4.0
ipython                                  8.26.0
isodate                                  0.6.1
itsdangerous                             2.2.0
jedi                                     0.19.1
Jinja2                                   3.1.4
jsonpatch                                1.33
jsonpickle                               3.2.2
jsonpointer                              3.0.0
kiwisolver                               1.4.5
kubernetes                               30.1.0
langchain                                0.2.10
langchain-community                      0.2.9
langchain-core                           0.2.22
langchain-openai                         0.1.17
langchain-text-splitters                 0.2.2
langsmith                                0.1.93
looseversion                             1.3.0
lxml                                     5.2.2
markdown-it-py                           3.0.0
MarkupSafe                               2.1.5
marshmallow                              3.21.3
matplotlib                               3.9.1
matplotlib-inline                        0.1.7
mdurl                                    0.1.2
mmh3                                     4.1.0
monotonic                                1.6
mpmath                                   1.3.0
msgspec                                  0.18.6
multidict                                6.0.5
mypy-extensions                          1.0.0
networkx                                 3.3
nibabel                                  5.2.1
nipype                                   1.8.6
numpy                                    1.26.4
oauthlib                                 3.2.2
onnxruntime                              1.18.1
openai                                   1.36.1
opentelemetry-api                        1.25.0
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-common 1.25.0
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-proto-grpc   1.25.0
opentelemetry-instrumentation            0.46b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-asgi       0.46b0
opentelemetry-instrumentation-fastapi    0.46b0
opentelemetry-proto                      1.25.0
opentelemetry-sdk                        1.25.0
opentelemetry-semantic-conventions       0.46b0
opentelemetry-util-http                  0.46b0
orjson                                   3.10.6
overrides                                7.7.0
packaging                                24.1
pandas                                   2.2.2
parso                                    0.8.4
pathlib                                  1.0.1
pdfminer.six                             20231228
pdfplumber                               0.11.2
pillow                                   10.4.0
pip                                      24.1.2
posthog                                  3.5.0
prompt_toolkit                           3.0.47
protobuf                                 4.25.3
prov                                     2.0.1
pure_eval                                0.2.3
pyasn1                                   0.6.0
pyasn1_modules                           0.4.0
pycparser                                2.22
pydantic                                 2.8.2
pydantic_core                            2.20.1
pydot                                    3.0.1
Pygments                                 2.18.0
pylatexenc                               2.10
pymongo                                  4.8.0
pyparsing                                3.1.2
pypdfium2                                4.30.0
PyPika                                   0.48.9
pyproject_hooks                          1.1.0
pyreadline3                              3.4.1
python-dateutil                          2.9.0.post0
python-dotenv                            1.0.1
python-multipart                         0.0.9
pytils                                   0.4.1
pytz                                     2024.1
pyvis                                    0.3.2
pyxnat                                   1.6.2
PyYAML                                   6.0.1
rdflib                                   6.3.2
regex                                    2024.5.15
requests                                 2.32.3
requests-oauthlib                        2.0.0
rich                                     13.7.1
rsa                                      4.9
scipy                                    1.14.0
setuptools                               58.1.0
shellingham                              1.5.4
simplejson                               3.19.2
six                                      1.16.0
sniffio                                  1.3.1
soupsieve                                2.5
SQLAlchemy                               2.0.31
stack-data                               0.6.3
starlette                                0.37.2
sympy                                    1.13.1
tenacity                                 8.5.0
tiktoken                                 0.7.0
tokenizers                               0.19.1
tomli                                    2.0.1
tools                                    0.1.9
tqdm                                     4.66.4
traitlets                                5.14.3
traits                                   6.3.2
typer                                    0.12.3
typing_extensions                        4.12.2
typing-inspect                           0.9.0
tzdata                                   2024.1
urllib3                                  2.2.2
uvicorn                                  0.30.3
watchfiles                               0.22.0
wcwidth                                  0.2.13
websocket-client                         1.8.0
websockets                               12.0
Werkzeug                                 3.0.3
wikipedia                                1.4.0
wrapt                                    1.16.0
yarl                                     1.9.4
youtube-transcript-api                   0.6.2
zipp                                     3.19.2

Moreover, in case i want to have this "change" online, how can i handle it?
According to the new specifications, the new import should be:
from collections.abc import Sequence

so I tried to update the Github workflow as follows, but anyway i get the same error:
name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App

env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: MYWEBAPP    # Set this to the name of your Azure Web App
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.12'         # Set this to the Python version to use

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v3.0.0
        with:
          python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}
          cache: 'pip'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          source venv/bin/activate
          pip install -r requirements.txt

      - name: Debug before patching
        run: |
          source venv/bin/activate
          echo "Checking for incorrect imports in pathlib.py before patching:"
          grep 'from collections import Sequence' venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pathlib.py || true

      - name: Patch pathlib.py to fix import error
        run: |
          source venv/bin/activate
          echo "Patching pathlib.py..."
          sed -i 's/from collections import Sequence/from collections.abc import Sequence/' venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pathlib.py || true

      - name: Debug after patching
        run: |
          source venv/bin/activate
          echo "Checking for incorrect imports in pathlib.py after patching:"
          grep 'from collections import Sequence' venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pathlib.py || true
          echo "Checking for correct imports in pathlib.py after patching:"
          grep 'from collections.abc import Sequence' venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pathlib.py || true

      - name: Check Python Path and Virtual Environment
        run: |
          source venv/bin/activate
          python -c "import sys; print('Python executable:', sys.executable); print('Python path:', sys.path);"

      - name: Clean up and rebuild
        run: |
          source venv/bin/activate
          pip cache purge
          python -m pip uninstall -y -r requirements.txt
          pip install -r requirements.txt

      - name: Create .env file with secrets
        run: |
          source venv/bin/activate
          echo "SECRET_KEY=${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }}" >> .env
          echo "DATABASE_URL=${{ secrets.DATABASE_URL }}" >> .env
          # Add other secrets as needed

      # Optional: Add step to run tests here (PyTest, Django test suites, etc.)

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            .
            !venv/

  deploy:
    permissions:
      contents: none
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Development'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: .

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}


Any idea how to handle this issue?
Thanks
stefano
UPDATE
I removed the pathlib from the requirements.txt. Now when performing the pip list is no more present. I tried again to deploy on azure web app using the following workflow:
name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App

env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: MYAPPNAMEHERE  # set this to the name of your Azure Web App
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.12'              # set this to the Python version to use

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v3.0.0
        with:
          python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}
          cache: 'pip'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          source venv/bin/activate
          pip install -r requirements.txt

      - name: Create .env file with secrets
        run: |
          source venv/bin/activate
          # MY SECRETS HERE

      # Optional: Add step to run tests here (PyTest, Django test suites, etc.)

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            .
            !venv/

  deploy:
    permissions:
      contents: none
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Development'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: .

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}

the build and deploy is successful but when i try to reach the URL i get the following error:
2024-07-23T19:15:46  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.
Starting Log Tail -n 10 of existing logs ----
/appsvctmp/volatile/logs/runtime/container.log 
2024-07-23T19:15:07.6456388Z     import zipfile
2024-07-23T19:15:07.6456426Z   File "/opt/python/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/zipfile/__init__.py", line 2298, in <module>
2024-07-23T19:15:07.6456461Z     from ._path import (  # noqa: E402
2024-07-23T19:15:07.6456498Z   File "/opt/python/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/zipfile/_path/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
2024-07-23T19:15:07.6456532Z     import pathlib
2024-07-23T19:15:07.6456583Z   File "/tmp/8dcab4922f16912/antenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
2024-07-23T19:15:07.6540975Z     from collections import Sequence
2024-07-23T19:15:07.6552283Z ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (/opt/python/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/collections/__init__.py)
2024-07-23T19:15:07.6938964Z Using packages from virtual environment antenv located at /tmp/8dcab4922f16912/antenv.
2024-07-23T19:15:07.6939279Z Updated PYTHONPATH to '/opt/startup/app_logs:/tmp/8dcab4922f16912/antenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages'
Ending Log Tail of existing logs ---

UPDATE2
Here's the full log from the AZURE environment:
 Ok
2024-07-24T09:12:07.5038227
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:14:30.241668
   _____                               
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:14:30.2416986
  /  _  \ __________ _________   ____  
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:14:30.2417027
 /  /_\  \\___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \ 
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:14:30.2417061
/    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/ 
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:14:30.2417091
\____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:14:30.2417123
        \/      \/                  \/ 
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:14:30.2417152
A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:14:30.2417181
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:14:30.2417208
Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:14:30.2417236
Python 3.12.2
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:14:30.2417265
Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:14:33.404157
Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:14:33.4706048
WEBSITES_INCLUDE_CLOUD_CERTS is not set to true.
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:14:33.666483
App Command Line not configured, will attempt auto-detect
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:14:33.6768318
Launching oryx with: create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -virtualEnvName antenv -defaultApp /opt/defaultsite
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:14:33.8481797
Found build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'. Deserializing it...
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:14:33.8585516
Build Operation ID: 6ecd8ae9aa5053e9
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:14:33.8748342
Oryx Version: 0.2.20240501.1, Commit: f83f88d3cfb8bb6d3e2765e1dcd218eb0814a095, ReleaseTagName: 20240501.1
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:14:33.8735793
Output is compressed. Extracting it...
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:14:33.8748588
Extracting '/home/site/wwwroot/output.tar.gz' to directory '/tmp/8dcabbe3278e60f'...
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.2154319
App path is set to '/tmp/8dcabbe3278e60f'
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.266784
Detected an app based on Flask
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.2668859
Generating `gunicorn` command for 'app:app'
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.2941587
Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.4429952
Using packages from virtual environment antenv located at /tmp/8dcabbe3278e60f/antenv.
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.4430281
Updated PYTHONPATH to '/opt/startup/app_logs:/tmp/8dcabbe3278e60f/antenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages'
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8319585
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8330992
  File "/opt/python/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 26, in <module>
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8341836
    import importlib.metadata as importlib_metadata
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.83509
  File "/opt/python/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8433323
    import pathlib
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8440429
  File "/tmp/8dcabbe3278e60f/antenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8448331
    from collections import Sequence
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8448574
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (/opt/python/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/collections/__init__.py)
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8519426
  Warning
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8519996
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8520042
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8520074
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8520105
  File "/opt/python/3.12.2/bin/gunicorn", line 5, in <module>
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8523137
    from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8523315
  File "/opt/python/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 9, in <module>
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8528817
    from gunicorn.app.base import Application
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8528965
  File "/opt/python/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 11, in <module>
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.853553
    from gunicorn import util
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.853568
  File "/opt/python/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 28, in <module>
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8535727
    import importlib_metadata
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8535762
  File "/tmp/8dcabbe3278e60f/antenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8538785
    import zipp
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8538836
  File "/tmp/8dcabbe3278e60f/antenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/zipp/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8538871
    import zipfile
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8538902
  File "/opt/python/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/zipfile/__init__.py", line 2298, in <module>
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8545671
    from ._path import (  # noqa: E402
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8545804
  File "/opt/python/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/zipfile/_path/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8616653
    import pathlib
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8727205
  File "/tmp/8dcabbe3278e60f/antenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8727371
    from collections import Sequence
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8727415
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (/opt/python/3.12.2/lib/python3.12/collections/__init__.py)
  Ok
2024-07-24T09:15:26.8727415


So why don't you just import it from collections.abc like you're supposed to and like you already know?

Some library is outdated and / or incompatible with the Python version. Show us your pip list and the full error traceback for details.

Any idea how to handle this issue? Not specifically, because you have not shown us exactly where the import error occurs.  We only know it happens "somewhere in your code".

@user240152285 If possible, Share your github repo?

@AsleshaKantamsetti Here on SO you share the code, no links, no pictures.

@nocomment because this import occurs in pathlib.py that is not under my control

@KlausD. i updated the post with the full result of the pip list

@JohnGordon sorry, maybe i was not clear enough. I added details in my post

You shouldn't need pathlib as an external module at all; it was added to base Python in version 3.4 (ten years ago!).  I would remove that module altogether.

It's odd that it found the external pathlib module first, instead of the built-in one.  Usually the system libraries are first in the module search path, specifically to avoid this kind of problem.  Did you alter your module search path to put /tmp/8dca9c76a13f465/antenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages first?

@JohnGordon thanks for your support. i didn't alter my module search path. I perform the changes you suggested before, but again error (i updated the post above)

Please edit the question and show us the output of this code import sys; print(sys.path)

2024-07-23T19:15:07.6939279Z Updated PYTHONPATH to ... This log output tells me that the module search path has been altered.  Do you know what is doing that?

@JohnGordon i added the full log directly from the azure resource just to have additional details about your question

I have exactly the same issue.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77678790/importerror-cannot-import-name-sequence-from-collections-azure-linux-we
It doesn't matter what you do in your user code or the pipeline.  It gets overtaken by the pathlib.py in the docker container running the web app.

I have a support ticket open with MS as part of my VS subscription.  I'll let you know how I get on.

Sequence is now available in collection.abc module. This change was added in version 3.3.
For reference check this document
Below code work for me.
I am using a simple Flask app to use Sequence and deployed to azure.
app.py:
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from collections.abc import Sequence

app = Flask(__name__)

def is_sequence(obj):
    try:
        return isinstance(eval(obj), Sequence) and not isinstance(eval(obj), str)
    except (NameError, SyntaxError):
        return False

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def check_sequence():
    obj = request.args.get('obj', '')
    if is_sequence(obj):
        return jsonify({'result': True, 'message': f'{obj} is a sequence.'})
    else:
        return jsonify({'result': False, 'message': f'{obj} is not a sequence.'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

OUTPUT:
Locally:


Azure:



Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately the issue is in the pathlib module that is handled directly on Azure side, it's not my application code.

Hello, did you find a solution for this? I'm facing the same issue. Thanks in advance.
